# Code generation tool for object wrapping

Tags: java, code-generation

Imagine you have to wrap an instance of a `java.sql.ResultSet`. You can't extend it because you don't know what is the concrete class implementing `ResultSet` being actually instantiated. You can just aggregate the instance, implement `ResultSet` and override all the methods.

Now imagine you want to change the behavior of just *one* method. All the other overridden methods are just a long boilerplate like this:

```
public void foo() {
    wrapped.foo();
}
```

Do you know any automatic code-generation tool that can perform this job for me (either standalone or included into common IDEs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Eclipse**, create a class with the ResultSet as a member, put the cursor on this member and then choose the menu "Source > Generate delegate Methods".

[image]

Check the methods you want to generate delegates for and it's done.

Comment: That's really cute. Something I didn't notice in my Eclipse. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any decent IDE should be able to do that. E.g. in InteilliJ Idea: Code -> Generate -> Delegate Methods

This option becomes available if the class has a member field with a type that the class implements/extends.